# How to get news_from_date and news_to_date?

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, magento-1

I have this code in my foreach:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getName() , 'name') ?>
```

How to get **news_from_date** and **news_to_date** with the same structure?

Comment: it is important where the foreach is and which class $_item belongs to

Answer (score 1):

Try Below code:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getNewsFromDate() , 'news_from_date') ?>

<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_item, $_item->getNewsToDate() , 'news_to_date') ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use

```
echo $item->getData('news_from_date');

echo $item->getData('news_to_date');
```